# Magnetic fields in plasma at equilibrium

Tags: plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

I'm wondering if it is possible to have a plasma reach an equilibrium state where no more entropy is produced but it still has frozen-in magnetic field lines. The problem is the field lines have a tension which could take the fluid out of equilibrium, and any current parallel to the electric field in the rest frame of the fluid produces entropy via Joule heating.

To be more specific, I'm wondering if there are known (probably highly idealized) solutions to dissipative magnetohydronamic equations which involve non-zero magnetic field and variation in pressure, temperature and so on.

I'm especially curious if it's possible to have an equilibrium solution compatible with general relativity. I would expect the fluid velocity would need to be proportional to a timelike Killing vector along which the magnetic field and thermodynamic quantities do not change, and this seems quite restrictive.

Comment: I don't believe that there are many analytic solutions for ideal MHD; my guess is that adding resistive effects (e.g., $\sim\eta\nabla^2\mathbf B$ term) probably means there are no analytic solutions.

Comment: Well you should be careful.  A current parallel to an electric field is not sufficient to cause Joule heating.  If the electric field is quasi-static, then the energy/momentum transfers are time reversible (i.e., think of an electron falling through the effects of an electric potential).  Also, the general rule in MHD is that magnetic tension acts to balance/counteract pressure.  So there are force-free equations in MHD, but MHD has a great deal of limitations over kinetic physics.  For instance, it is only applicable for large spatial scales relative to the ion gyroradius.

Comment: @honeste_vivere I'm wondering if you know any references to the quasi-static situation? I'm taking this to mean that dissipative processes are allowed but the plasma is in a balanced state where no entropy is produced. I have a paper (dissipative string fluids) up on arxiv today where I demonstrate some things which I believe apply to MHD in this situation, but I am an outsider on this subject

Comment: @octonion - It just comes from the following.  dW/dt = $\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v}$, where $\mathbf{F}$ is a force and dW/dt is change in work/energy with respect to time.  For the Lorentz force, the magnetic contribution (if quasi-static) is clearly zero since $(\mathbf{v} \times \mathbf{B}) \cdot \mathbf{v}$ = 0.  If the electric field is electrostatic, then one can recall $\oint \ \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l}$ = 0, which is true of any conservative force.  It's another way of saying that the path integral is path independent.

Comment: @octonion - Thus, even though one can change the kinetic energy of a particle or particles, under the influence of quasi-static fields the effect will be time reversible.  As for references, you can look at any E&M textbook on electro- and magnetostatics (e.g., Griffiths or Jackson).  Additionally, introducing dissipation is, by definition, going to introduce entropy, correct?  How are you accomplishing this in a self-consistent fashion?

Comment: @honeste_vivere I mean that the possibility of dissipation is there so that, for instance, if the velocity of the fluid has a divergence bulk viscosity effects will increase entropy. So there needs to be the restriction that the fluid is incompressible. There are a number of these restrictions, and you can show certain things like the existence of a timelike Killing vector.